# How to measure integration test coverage when the tests are in a different java project

Tags: integration-testing, code-coverage

I wish to capture integration test coverage for a java project. 
However the tests are present in a different java project. 
We are using jacoco for capturing the coverage .

How can i capture the integration test coverage in this case ?

Thanks